# Transition from visual studio to wix installer

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix-extension, wix3.7

I have visual studio installer installs everything in Programfiles. I have done transition and create new WIX installer. Wix installer alone works fine but when I try to upgrade my old version I get two application installed.

Wix installs in LocalAppData and old installer installs in Program files. I have fixed peruser and per machine issue but still new installer is not working on upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If one is simply an upgrade of the other, they should have the same UpgradeCode property value. If you need to check the MSI file of the old installer for the UpgradeCode, use a tool like [InstEdit!](http://www.instedit.com).